# GLib-GIO-Message and Gtk-WARNING on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, gtk, ibus

Trying to run a Python script on my Ubuntu 16.04 I got this following message:

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

(python:14505): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(python:14505): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(python:14505): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(python:14505): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed

(python:14505): Gtk-WARNING **: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)

(python:14505): Gtk-WARNING **: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
```

It does not seems to affect the code, but I wonder why I suddenly have this error message. Somebody has an idea what checkups should I do?

Comment: As far as I know, these are *warnings*, not *errors* and happen with about any GUI program you start from the Terminal.

Comment: Those warnings should still be looked at. Just because on the command line does not mean they are meaningless. It seems the versions of python-gobject included with 16.04 don't match the versions of GLib.

Comment: What happens if you run http://pastie.org/10937021? Are you using ibus for alternate input methods? (Open question.)

Comment: After some feedback, at this point, I can only suggest filing a bug report on Launchpad. Good luck.

Comment: The same problem suddenly happened on my Ubuntu 16.04 system this morning. No alternative input methods as far as I know. The pastie linked by @andlabs doesn't run on my system - I don't have GTK installed.

Comment: @Gabriel if that exact message shows up then you do have GTK+ installed, just not python-gobject or python3-gobject. "IM contexts" are a GTK+ feature. (GModule is just a wrapper around `dlopen()`.)